# Using a c++ library in my PHP Extension: undefined symbol: mpfr_get_emin_min

Tags: php, c++, php-extension, mpfr

Trying to compile my own MPFR Module for PHP, using the mpfr.so library. My extension itself has a simple ping function, which simply returns "pong" to verify, that the extension is actually loaded, and another function, which returns the following:

```
return ("MPFR library: %-12s\nMPFR header:  %s (based on %d.%d.%d)\n",
            mpfr_get_version(), MPFR_VERSION_STRING, MPFR_VERSION_MAJOR,
            MPFR_VERSION_MINOR, MPFR_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL);
```

This should print the current mpfr lib version. When i compile the php extension, the compiler process has no error. I copy the output so file into the process of PHP modules, and after calling my php script, it actually says `undefined symbol: mpfr_get_emin_min`

So first i thought, that the library output probably does not know any of the lib mpfr, so i added the compiler flag `-lmpfr -lgmp` at the very end, but somehow it does nothing.

The file itself simply uses the `<mpfr.h>`, and i think it is correctly in the extension and available.

Comment: In which language is that function compiled? C or C++? If it has been compiled in C++, maybe extern "C" can help.

Comment: It is compiled into c++, uses extern "C" already :)

Comment: I'm wondering how this can be possible; FYI, `mpfr_get_version()` just returns a pointer to a constant string, without referencing anything. There must be something specific to PHP (a clash with another component?), but I don't know anything about PHP. Is it normal that you have a format string without something like `printf`? And perhaps you should give a list of the referenced symbols of your compiled PHP extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension does not know of the function. You have to include the mpfr lib into your extension, so it will be compiled / loaded into it.